# Converting data types in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I need to change some data types. I have tried using the `CAST` keyword, but it is not fixing the issue. Any suggestions on how to re-write these two lines with `CAST` statements?

1. Data loss might occur when casting from `VarChar(100)` to `VarChar(20)`.

Code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @variableId = variableId
FROM @tempTable
```

2. Data loss might occur when casting from `NVarChar(512)` to `NVarChar`.

Code:

```
SELECT myVariable
FROM tableName
```

I tried doing something like the following, but still produces an error:

```
CAST((myVariable) as nvarchar)
```

Comment: What is your problem?  When you shorten a character string, you might lose data.  That is expected and why you get the warning.

Comment: Please be more specific. What did you try? How does your data and schema looks like? The messages you provided are quite self-explaining: Your target type is to small to keep data from the source data type.

Comment: Okay, give me a minute and I will update the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CAST` is used for converting between data types. It sounds more like you should use `LEFT` instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @variableId = LEFT(variableId,20)
FROM @tempTable
```

This won't give you any warning as the system assumes you already know you're going to lose the right 80 characters.

Answer (score 0):

For using `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar, myVariable)
```

Is a valid syntax and also:

```
CONVERT(varchar(20), myVariable)
```

---

But for getting a part of a string we use `SUBSTRING()` or `LEFT()`  or `RIGHT()` functions like this:

- `SUBSTRING( value_expression , start_expression , length_expression )`

  > Returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression.
- `LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )`

  > Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number of characters.
- `RIGHT ( character_expression , integer_expression )`

  > Returns the right part of a character string with the specified number of characters.